# To create a class with Controls as element and populate these controls dynamically on the run

Tags: c#, winforms

Using C# to create window forms with MS visual studio, I would like to create a form that have 20 other forms being loaded depends on a selection from combobox. 
All these forms being loaded share ***some*** common TextBox / Combobox, for e.g.

form 1:

> Dynamically adding TextBox username / dept / Dept_manager and Combobox
>   dept_location / dept_code / Num_of_washroom

form 2:

> Dynamically adding TextBox username / dept / Dept_manager and Combobox
>   dept_location / <s>dept_code</s> / <s>Num_of_washroom</s> / dept_ID

form 3:

> Dynamically adding TextBox username / <s>dept</s> / Dept_manager /
>   Dept_code and Combobox dept_location  / <s>dept_code</s> /
>   Num_of_washroom

...

The question is: **instead of hardcoding all the textbox / combobox in a nested if statement:**

```
if (combobox.text == "NewYork")
{
  TextBox dept = new TextBox();
  dept.location = ...
  dept.size = ...
 }
```

**is there a better way to manage these (i.e. a class)?**  With 20 forms and 10+ controls each, hardcoding will create unnecessary large bytes

I have tried to provide simple code but fails to make myself clear on what I wanted.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: new controls arent being created anywhere; `office` just declares some.  But why do you need new controls for NY vs Denver - no one but you would know if you used the same ones and just disabled "dept_location" or made it invisible if/when it is not needed.

Comment: @Plutonix My form will have 20+ controls adding on the run, and 20+ offices, I am merely looking for a way to, say if I change something for an office, I am able to update it by just adding/ removing "Controls.Add(<office.control>);", rather than editing a bunch of related control properties.  Not sure if I made myself clear haha

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not enough detail in your question to know exactly what you are asking. Maybe you want to implement a `UserControl`, which is like a `Form` (i.e. can be designed) but can be added as a control to a `Form`. Or maybe with your `office` type, you could get away with just displaying its contents using `PropertyGrid`. It's not really clear why simply handling things dynamically in your `Form` class itself is not working for you.

Comment: @PeterDuniho thanks, I will rephase my question.  The reason I provided with the code is I was hoping to serve a better explanation.  I will go straightly to my question

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it like this:

1)Create, set Visible to folse and Add all possible controls (TextBox etc.) on FlowLayoutPanel in design time or on form initialization. Flow panel will handle controls placing automatically.

2)Create/load special table with active controls names for each configuration.

3)When combobox item is selected apply selected configuration (set visible controls) using control's "Name" property to identify controls:

```
    public class OfficeFormsConfig
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string[] @Fields { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }

    void FillOfficesCombo()
    {
        var arrViewConfigs = new List<OfficeFormsConfig>();
        //---Load from DB or File (but here is hard coded as an example)-
        arrViewConfigs.Add(new OfficeFormsConfig()
            {
                Name = "NewYork",
                @Fields = new string[] { "username", "dept", "deptManager", "dept_location" }
            });
        arrViewConfigs.Add(new OfficeFormsConfig()
        {
            Name = "Denver",
            @Fields = new string[] { "username", "deptManager", "Num_of_washroom" }
        });
        //---------------------------------------------------------------

        foreach (var config in arrViewConfigs)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(config);
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OfficeFormsConfig cfg = comboBox1.SelectedItem as OfficeFormsConfig;
        foreach (Control ctl in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            ctl.Visible = cfg.Fields.Any(ctlName => ctlName == ctl.Name);
        }
    }
```